# How to share selective windows using Windows Desktop Sharing API

Tags: c#, .net, rdp, desktop-sharing

I am using Windows Desktop Sharing API to write a desktop sharing application.

The ultimate goal of mine is to share the complete desktop except few windows. I am able to get the windows from ApplicationFilter.Windows and also able to make the Shared property to false for the window that I don't want to share on the viewer end. But the problem is that it turns the non-shared windows to black rectangle on the other end. How can I make it completely transparent on viewer end?

Fahim

Answer (score 0):

While I can't help with your API, I can recommend that you try Mikogo if you are looking for an easy way to desktop share and hide certain applications. Our Application Selection feature allows you to easily select which applications other viewers can see - if you prefer to hide an application it will show up as a blank window. Try it out here and let me know what you think - http://www.mikogo.com.

Thanks!

Spencer Dunfee
Mikogo Team
sdunfee@mikogo.com

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, just to let you know, we don't use signatures here. Also, if you're advertising your own work, you'll want to make it very explicit that it is yours (which this is reasonably, but once your signature is removed it will be less so)